# Why can't browser.getRequest get data？

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools, wdio

I use wdio intercept service to test the network interface，This is his [official document](https://webdriver.io/docs/wdio-intercept-service). I used it completely according to his instructions, but I didn't get the expected results

this is my test.js

```js
   it("test a", async () => {
        browser.url("https://www.amazon.in/")

        let input = await $("#twotabsearchtextbox")
        input.setValue("mobile")
        await browser.pause(3000)

        await browser.expectRequest("GET", "/api/2017/suggestions", "200")

        let searchSuggestions = await browser.getRequest(
            "GET",
            "https://completion.amazon.in/api/2017/suggestions"
        )

        console.log("Response Headers", searchSuggestions)
        expect(searchSuggestions).to.have.length.above(0)
    })
```

when I run it, I got:

```bash
expected [] to have a length above +0 but got +0
```

This is my repo for test: https://github.com/Ruobei/wdioTest.git

I checked a lot of materials, but I didn't find the reason, nor did I find any other calling methods。If anyone knows how to solve it, it will be appreciated。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the setup function in order to assess request called. Please add browser.setupInterceptor() after the browser.url() command.

More details can be found here: https://webdriver.io/docs/wdio-intercept-service/#api

Answer (score 0):

Try with 4.2.2 version:

```
npm install wdio-intercept-service@4.2.2
```

Comment: I used version 4.2.2 before